# Multiple JSONArrayRequests

Tags: android, json

Folks, I have a big problem I cant see to solve on my own.
I have an app that I call a JSONArrayRequest to populate a list, it works fine. however when I click an item on that lists it takes me to another activity and when I try to call JSONArrayRequest from my new Actitivies' adapter class the call is skipped its like its omitting the call.

Please see at the attached code:

```
ServiceProviderAdapter.Java

public ServiceProviderAdapter(int rowLayout, Context context) {

        List<ServiceProvider> DetailsItems = new ArrayList<ServiceProvider>();
        sendJSONRequest();
        //LyInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

sendJSONRequest call

```
private void sendJSONRequest() {

    //List<ServiceProvider> serviceProviderList=new ArrayList<ServiceProvider>();
    JsonArrayRequest dq;
    //RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

    dq= new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            serviceProviderList = parseJSONResponse(jsonArray);
            setDetailsItems(serviceProviderList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            VolleyLog.d("E", "Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
        }
    });




    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(dq,"DetailJSONTag");


}

 public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

When I try to debug my code and the cursor is at the JSONArrayRequest line it goes straight to next line:

```
  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(dq,"DetailJSONTag");


 cardDetailActivity.Java

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.card_list);

    //CardView cardView= (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adapter=new ServiceProviderAdapter(R.layout.card_user_details,this);
    recList.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    if (llm.getItemCount()==0)
    {

        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }else{
        hidePDialog();
    }
```

I am adding a breakpoint just after a new instance of ServiceAdapter Class is called, and on the constructor for my call I want to fill my List Object with the data returning from the JSONArrayrequest. The Activity is filling the view with a RecycleView in it.

I dont understand why it works on my first activity but on the new call it gets omitted.

Some help please

thanks

Comment: have you try to put breakpoints inside the callback methods, onResponse and onErrorResponse to see whether it is executed or not? Also post your addToRequestQueue method too if possible.

Comment: I added breakpoints to the callbacks but the cursor dont even get inside the calls. The addToRequestQueue is the AppController.java call that uses Volley library.

Comment: try to clear project, sometimes the debugger just go crazy

Comment: Didnt work...Quick question, I need some help in the creation of a recycleview object, please see code above

Comment: Folks, I havent been able to fix this on my own. I even created a new project with just a JSONArrayRequest call and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

1. When calling JSONArrayRequest and using a RecycleView, it wont work due to not having network connection at the time the request is sent for a response.
2. Call for the JSON object/array has to be called Asynchronously before setting the adapter for RecycleView, in order to do this, one must
   Create a class extending AsyncTask and make a HTTP connection and once the connection has been made and response been parsed then you can set the adapter for the RecycleView.

Comment: Can you put any example ? because a synchronized is very extended