# Second JsonArrayRequest is not working

Tags: android, arrays, json, request, android-volley

I have an issue. I am consuming a web service from my android app using Volley JsonArrayRequest. The first request is getting the page list, which works perfectly fine. However when I click on the button to go to the page and at the oncreate method of the activity, second request which should get the contents of the page is not working.I am not using recyclerview by the way. I debugged the project and what I saw was interesting. Debugger is completely omitting the whole JsonArrayRequest block. Is that a bug? Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: show us your code and where isn't working

Comment: I've found the solution. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157782/multiple-jsonarrayrequests